# bad syntax for struct tag value - structtag

Tags: go

Followed the convention by using `key:"value"` in the struct tags in the below type definition:

```
type Foo struct {
    A int `tag1: "first tag" tag2: "second tag"`
    B string
}

func main() {
    f := Foo{A: 10, B: "Salutations"}
    g := &Foo{A: 10, B: "Salutations"}

    // 1. Reading struct tags from struct
    fType := reflect.TypeOf(f)
    field, ok := fType.FieldByName("A")
    if !ok {
        panic("no elements")
    }
    var tag reflect.StructTag = field.Tag
    tagString := string(tag)
    fmt.Println(tagString)

    // 2. Reading struct tags from pointer to struct
    fType = reflect.TypeOf(g)
    field, ok = fType.Elem().FieldByName("A")
    if !ok {
        panic("no elements")
    }
    tag = field.Tag
    tagString = string(tag)
    fmt.Println(tagString)

}
```

---

Compiler acceots the code, but,

Linter gives warning: `struct field tag` tag1: "first tag" tag2: "second tag" `not compatible with reflect.StructTag.Get: bad syntax for struct tag value`

Is the tag syntax(using spaces) not in compliance with `StructTag` string?

Answer (score 0):

> Is the tag syntax(using spaces) not in compliance with StructTag string?

Yes.